# Launch Java application from another application

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

What I want to do is to have my main Java application to update another java application using Java Web Start and then run the second application "silently" upon user request.

I know Runtime.exec to call javaws and silently import the second application in the cache. I can do that when the first application runs and then I am sure I have an updated copy of the second application. My problem is how to run the second application without showing the Java Web start "Verifying application" window.

Doing some research I see no way to avoid that if I execute the .jnlp. I am wondering whether I can run the second application calling directly the downloaded jar files by passing Java Web  Start.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This may cause the security problem - let say you have application A.jar is signed and trusted, you want create application B that is not signed and managed and run it from A.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two possibilities here:

- you can use the [JNLP Api service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html) and use the `DownloadService`;
- or use the `URLClassLoader` and load the remote class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this what you want to do, may be for you it seems as a trick around, forgive me if so...

Why don't you run it as exe, by using process object?

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\...Desktop\\MyExe.exe").start();
```

And you can convert your app to exe easily by using [jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I thought of the Java Web start solution in order to be able to update the second application using webstart's auto update functionality. How will I be able to update the second application if I distribut it as an exe. Updating-starting-stopping the second application should be invisible to the user?

Comment: I think at any case, you should notify the user about the update, an example of the exe of a java file is [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/). It is a free, open-source download management tool, it also has the auto update feature you want.
I hope I helped.